# PHP and XML - Set unique ids in document

Tags: php, xml, unique, identifier

i have this script example:

```
while (count($xml->xpath('*[@id="' . $id . '"]/@id')) > 0)
{
    $id = 'example_' . ++$x;
}
```

But if i check this with 1.000 Childrens in the element, i must wait more than a hour for an response.

How i could quicker check if a id exists?

**Thank's in Advance for your Tip!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks @michi:**

I modified the example and this is the final answer:

```
$ids = $xml->xpath('*[@id="' . $id . '"]/@id');
if(count($ids) > 0)
{
    $ids = $xml->xpath('*[starts-with(@id, "example_")]/@id');
    $id = max(array_map(
            function($a)
            {
                list(, $id) = explode('_', $a);
                return intval($id);
            }, $ids)) + 1;
    $id = 'example_' . $id;
}
```

**=}**

Answer (score 1):

get a unique id by grabbing the highest id and add 1 to it.
As you didn't provide an XML, I assume the following for my example:

```
<elements>
    <element id="example_1" />
    <element id="example_5" />
    <element id="example_27" />
</elements>
```

This is the code (PHP >= 5.3 for inline function):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$ids = $xml->xpath("//element/@id");
$newid = max(array_map(
    function($a) {
        list(, $id) = explode("_", $a);
        return intval($id); }
    , $ids)) + 1;
$newid = "example_$newid";
echo $newid;
```

Output:

```
example_28
```

See it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/SFvf7v

Comments:
 1. the `xpath`expression in line 2 builds an array `$ids` of all ids in the XML
 2. we need to separate the `example` from the number at the `_` and change the number to `int` in order to perform `max()`, this is done with `array_map()`calling an inline function
 3. within this function, we use `list()` to grab that number part of the string seperated with `explode()` and return it as `int`

Comment: Great, thank you. But i really need "all" id attributes on document like this:
`  $ids = $xml->xpath('*[@id="example_' . $id . '"]/@id');
  if(count($ids) > 0)
  {
   $ids = $xml->xpath('*[@id="example_*"]/@id');
   $id = max(array_map(
     function($a) {
      list(, $id) = explode('_', $a);
      return intval($id);
     }, $ids)) + 2;
   $id = $exId . '_' . $id;
  }`

I looking for a xpath selector like the jquery selector $('[id^="example_' + id + '"]')... but as xpath ^^